# DexArchiveBuilderException

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I know that this question is already asked but the solutions provided  there are not working for me and i can't risk the build with d8 compiler. Here is the error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process E:\suv\Projects\SoundRecorder\ImageFetcher\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug
Error:com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process E:\suv\Projects\SoundRecorder\ImageFetcher\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug
Error:com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing Services/MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.class
Error:com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: class name (services/MyFirebaseInstanceIDService) does not match path (Services/MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.class)
```

Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ops.com.imagefetcher"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Please help me to fix this issue.

Edit: While trying to fix it I did "clean project" and one more error came out:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:clean'.
> Unable to delete directory: E:\suv\Projects\SoundRecorder\ImageFetcher\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug
```

Comment: Have you tried Cleaning and Rebuilding your project? Sometimes you might need to delete the apk from your phone or emulator as well. Could also result from a gradle dependency mismatch or using different versions of the same dependency. Do you have a larger stacktrace

Comment: Yes i have already tried that and there is no installed apk in the emulator.

Comment: Ensure you are in the `package` not `Android` view mode on the file tree on the left side. Press `Alt+1` if it is not open. Go to the `app\build` folder as stated and delete the build folder`. Dont worry, once you clean and rebuild it should regenerate all the files

Comment: some java.io.IOException while trying to delete build folder

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After doing clean build i got error:

```
execution failed for task ':app:clean'.
> Unable to delete directory: E:\suv\Projects\SoundRecorder\ImageFetcher\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug
```

Then I tried to delete the package manually from android studio but it showed some IOException error. Then what i did is: I closed the android studio and manually deleted the **debug** folder from "MyComputer/ThisPC" by following the path from error. After this fix, android studio successfully created the build.

Answer (score 2):

The casing in your path doesn't match:

**s**ervices/MyFirebaseInstanceIDService

**S**ervices/MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.class

Answer (score 1):

in gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```