# Error: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, dex

When I am trying to run app below error occur:

> Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
>   Error:com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process G:\Android\Fundraiser\BuyForFund\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug
>   Error:com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing App/AppController.class
>   Error:com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: class name (app/AppController) does not match path (App/AppController.class)
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process G:\Android\Fundraiser\BuyForFund\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug

AppContoller is inside java>app>AppController

**`Gradle.build`**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.buyforfund"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.chootdev:csnackbar:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library-material:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
}
```

Help me to solve this errors.

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'       add this in Gradle.build  under depedencies

Comment: compile 'com.google.guava:guava:23.3-android'  put in Gradle.vuild depenedcy

Comment: Possible duplicate :https://stackoverflow.com/a/48803568/7806873

Comment: As per answer in above link try to delete `debug` folder from `G:\Android\Fundraiser\BuyForFund\app\build\intermediates\classes` location as per error and then try with rebuild project.